# Storing Scraped data into Postgresql (PgAdmin) from twitter using API

Tags: postgresql, twitter, google-colaboratory

I am using the Twitter API to scrape data from Twitter and store the results into PostgreSQL. But whenever I execute the code, Below error appears.
[image]

Log File:
[image]

Pg_hba.conf:
[image]

postgresql.conf:
[image]

```
# Search for tweets
query = 'your_search_query'
tweets = api.search_tweets(q=query)

# Set the database credentials
host = 'localhost'
port = '5432'
database = 'postgres'
user = 'postgres'
password = 'mypass'

# Connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, port=port, dbname=database, user=user, password=password)

# Create a cursor object
cur = conn.cursor()

# Insert the scraped data into the database
for tweet in tweets:
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweets (id, text, created_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", 
(tweet.id_str, tweet.text, tweet.created_at))

# Commit the changes
conn.commit()

# Close the cursor and connection
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Services
[image: postgresqlserver]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `host` to `127.0.0.1` in your code, sometimes `localhost` fails to work with pg.